# grep without -P with the same result

Tags: bash, grep

My code:

```
cat json | grep -Po '(?<=Inne","index":)(.*?)(?=,)'
```

This give my number 21 how I can make this but without -P ? and got the same result? thx.

file json:

```
{"success":true,"msg":"","file_path":"","subtitle_list":[{"name":"Wył.","index":0,"selected":false},{"name":"1/21 Duński","index":1,"selected":false},{"name":"2/21 Niemiecki","index":2,"selected":false},{"name":"3/21 Angielski","index":3,"selected":false},{"name":"4/21 Hiszpański","index":4,"selected":false},{"name":"5/21 Francuski","index":5,"selected":false},{"name":"6/21 Włoski","index":6,"selected":false},{"name":"7/21 Niderlandzki","index":7,"selected":false},{"name":"8/21 Norweski","index":8,"selected":false},{"name":"9/21 Fiński","index":9,"selected":false},{"name":"10/21 Szwecki","index":10,"selected":false},{"name":"11/21 Angielski","index":11,"selected":false},{"name":"12/21 Niemiecki","index":12,"selected":false},{"name":"13/21 Angielski","index":13,"selected":false},{"name":"14/21 Hiszpański","index":14,"selected":false},{"name":"15/21 Francuski","index":15,"selected":false},{"name":"16/21 Włoski","index":16,"selected":false},{"name":"17/21 Niemiecki","index":17,"selected":false},{"name":"18/21 Hiszpański","index":18,"selected":false},{"name":"19/21 Francuski","index":19,"selected":false},{"name":"20/21 Włoski","index":20,"selected":false},{"name":"Inne","index":21,"selected":true}]}
```

Update:

Looks like I can use -E os not return warring.

os not support -P and I cant install jq, this is embedded os in blu-ray player.

Update:
Yes I can use awk or sed.

Comment: Why dont you want to use `-P` ? It's not possible to do a positive lookbehind without a flag like `-P` or `-E` anyways

Comment: I cant use -P, os not support

Comment: What's your OS ? Does your version of `grep` support the `-E` flag ? As you are parsing a json file, are you able to install `jq` on your machine ?

Comment: Yes I think I can use -E.

Comment: Does the embedded OS have `awk` or `sed` installed? I have a feeling those may be easier languages to implement this in.

Comment: Yes I can use sed or awk.

Comment: given that index is always a number: `cat json | grep -o 'Inne","index":[^,]*' | grep -o '[0-9]*$'`

Comment: Answers belong only in the answer section, not in questions. Either accept an answer; or if something was added as a comment, maybe suggest that its author add an answer (or even do so yourself, giving them credit and optionally marking the "community wiki" checkbox to disclaim credit yourself); but don't edit answers into questions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*Inne[^:]*:([^,]*).*/\1/' input_file
21
```

Comment: Rrrr I can't use -E for sed on this os :(, for home os working great.

Comment: @jasko887 Try `BRE sed` `sed 's/.*Inne[^:]*:\([^,]*\).*/\1/' file`